# knockout validation with a single error message for observable field constraints

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Is it possible to define a single error message for a validated observer, regardless of how many constraints it has?

For instance, this observable returns separate error messages for `required`, `minLength`, and `pattern`...

```
ko.observable()
    .extend({ 
         required: true,
         minLength: 3,
         pattern: {
             message: 'Hey this doesnt match my pattern',
             params: '^[A-Z0-9].$'
         }
     });
```

I want to use a single message like this...

```
ko.observable()
    .extend({ 
         message: "Required, alpha numerics, minimum 3 chars."
         required: true,
         minLength: 3,
         pattern: {
             params: '^[A-Z0-9].$'
         }
     });
```

We're building a tool/ui for developers, and I find it more practical to show a single message that reflects *all* constraints if the user inputs something invalid.

I tried the above, it doesn't work. I also inspected the validationModel and errors array, but could not get it to work. I suspect this is not supported, but I'm too new to ko to implement a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it is better to have validation error messages tell you exactly what validation has failed. E.g if I wrote "example@example.com" I don't want an error message to tell me that the field is required or needs minimum 3 chars.

The message in your example is better suited as inline help/tooltip, not as a validation message.

Also I don't think it is supported by knockout-validation

Comment: I hear ya, but we're building a tool for developers, and the ui is for their use, thx for the info